Quarto Manuscript - Compile from multiple QMD files
I am using a Quarto manuscript project. It looks great with all the content in a single file (index.qmd).
manuscript:
  article: index.qmd

However, I would like to split up the different sections into their own files, using a chapter-style approach similar to how I can do "chapters" with a book type project. How can I achieve this using the manuscript project type?

You can include files in same manner you would in TeX, e.g.:
{{< include _content.qmd >}}

See Quarto notes on inclusion of files.

Nice! FYI - I found that including headings in the included file may mess up the heading structure of the parent document. So this works at least if there are no sub-headings. I guess a follow-up would be how to get the heading levels to work.
